# Hibernate. Set string parameter as char 25

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, nativequery

I have an oracle database. I have query to table A, where column b is CHAR(25 BYTE). When i create by hibernate native query like 
`(select t.* from A t where t.b = :b).setParameter("b", "0123456789")` its returned an empty result.
When i create native query like `(select t.* from A t where t.b = :b).setParameter("b", "0123456789               ")` with 15 empty chars after '9' it returns an non empty result as expected. 
So my question is - what do I do to write a normal query with hibernate?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any different between the two query you created, only the length of parameter different.

Comment: @JohnJoe Because of the length 25 of the input parameter, the second query works as it should. So if i sent from my application java code input parameter for query with 10 symbols lenght it doesnt work. Is it possible to somehow indicate in hibernate that for this parameter, hibernate should send it as a char 25 or something like that

Comment: You have two 3 in second query.  Is this typo or you have value `01233456789` in database?

Comment: @JohnJoe sorry, i made a mistake when write second example. The input parameter is the same as in the first code example - 0123456789, but in second example after '9' it has 15 empty symbols. '0123456789' - its just for example input parameter

Comment: Are you sure your query is  correct ?  `"select t.* from A t.."` sounds weird to me

Comment: @JohnJoe yes. if it sounds weird to you think about it as pseudo code. Problem not in this place

Answer (score 0):

If you are positive that you want to ignore the trailing whitespaces the easiest solution (not the fastest) is to use the rtrim function inside the HQL:

```
(select t.* from A t where rtrim(t.b) = :b).setParameter("b", "0123456789")
```

An alternative solution is to use user types. Have a look here: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForDealingWithFixedLengthCHARFields

Comment: I decided it this way 'select t.* from A t where t.b = rpad(:b, 25)'

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.* from A t where t.b = rpad(:b, 25)
```

rpad - sql function to add blank characters to the right after '9'. 25 - it how many characters must be in this param 'b'. So if i use b as '0123456789' this func create b param as `'0123456789               '`